# How to add column name to the query result SPRING JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

For example, I've got such query:

```
@Query("SELECT u.name FROM User u")
public List<User> findAllUsers();
```

I know, this is not an optimal way to show all users, but it's just for example, my query is more complex.

I've got such answer:
[{"Tom Wally"}]

But I want to get:
[{"name":"Tom Wally"}]

How to add column name to custom query?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are talking about how return a response in a json format.

If you want a response in json-format you should create two classes like these, one when creating your object, and the other when creating the response from a list.

```html
public class UserResponseList extends ArrayList<UserResponse>(){

public UserResponseList(List <UserResponse> myList){ 
super(myList);
}

}
public class UserResponse(){

private String name;
}
```

finally ,you instantiate UserResponseList sending your list in constructor, and you have your json response with your specific format.

Comment: I can try... But do you think I really need this? Because, I already have json format when my query is not custom. For example with findAll(); [{"id":1,"name":"Tom Wally"}]

Comment: I understand you need a specific json response **[{"name":"Tom Wally"}]**, so, as you return a **List<User>** then you need to build a response as an arraylist with only specific fields you want to return in your json response.

Comment: there is some ways to return specific fields between objects, for example, you do not need **id** field, so you need a class without id field. I suggest you to see **orika** , it is a mapper tool to send attributes between objects. [http://orika-mapper.github.io/orika-docs/index.html](http://orika-mapper.github.io/orika-docs/index.html)